# Ошибка в коде EditText

Tags: java, android-edittext

`EditText` первая кнопка очищает, вторая кнопка восстанавливает текст, удаленный первой кнопкой. Что не так?

```
String text;

button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.getText().clear();
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text = editText.getText().toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте - [Что делать, когда кто то ответил на мой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправь этот листенер вот так

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text = editText.getText().toString();
        editText.getText().clear();
    }
});
```

А второй вот так

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setText(text);
        ...
```

Comment: спасибо очень помог